# what is the best way to embed a pdf from another server

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I am trying to embed a pdf in my web page, that is not in my server. Pdf.js doesn't support this
i tried using iframe and object but they won't work if the file was force downloaded.
I tried googling alot, I used google docs viewer but I've found it that it wouldn't be practical because it has a bandwidth limit and it's not compatiable with all browsers, I tried scribd API but it was laggy. Anyone have an idea of a way to do this?

Comment: download the pdf to the server ... then you can serve it from your domain through pdf.js

Comment: if the file was force downloaded you can change it using the browser

Comment: there are so many pdfs to view, I can't download them all to the server.
@samitha I don't understand your comment